# Is this properly termed "instantiation" if no instance is created?

Tags: java, instantiation

I have a class that only contains static methods. In order to make use of it, I execute the following code once, early in the project:

```
new SoundUtility();
```

Is this line of code considered to be an act of "instantiation" if no actual instance is obtained? All invocations in the project of the utility are static. Or is there another term to use to describe this?

If I don't execute the shown line of code, a static call throws an NPE.

Comment: Getting a null pointer exception when calling a `static` method sounds fishy. Are you sure your constructor doesn't have some side effects that your methods rely upon?

Comment: Because the methods are statics, there's no need to instantiate an object to use static methods.  You can use the methods using the class name.  For example, Math.sqrt(4).  The class is Math and the static method is sqrt().

Comment: You are right. The constructor is used to instantiate a class variable that is used by the static methods. When the class variable is invoked by the static method, it will be null unless the constructor had been called earlier. Probably not a great pattern on my part, though it has greatly facilitated other aspect of the code.

Comment: An actual instance *is* obtained. You just aren't storing the reference anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a constructor and creating an object. Even if you throw the resulting object  away immediately and the only effect was to initialize some class level global thing, it still counts as instantiating an object.

This is a really ugly way to do things, in case that wasn't evident. If you are going to have static state, which is bad enough,  it would be better to initialize it in a static initializer than in a constructor call.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my main question and gets into the issue that has always bothered me about how best to "wire up" the handling of sound-related duties. I've usually created a SoundUtility class as a wrapper for audio functionality and injected it to the necessary components. But it seems making the SoundUtility class static perhaps serves as a simpler solution. Placing the code in the constructor in a static block has eliminated the need to call `new SoundUtility()`. I'm not clear if there are downsides to making a static utility class in this way.